# Kerberos does not issue renewable tickets

Tags: kerberos

I am trying to issue a renewable ticket for my principal using a keytab (MIT KDC, Red Hat 7.4):

```
su - newuser
kinit -r 7d -kt /etc/security/keytabs/newuser.service.keytab newuser/mask1.myhost.com@EXAMPLE.COM
```

Looking at the flags:

```
[newuser@mask1 ~]$ klist -f
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_2824
Default principal: newuser/mask1.myhost.com@EXAMPLE.COM

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
09/27/2018 09:40:32  09/28/2018 09:40:32  krbtgt/EXAMPLE.COM@EXAMPLE.COM
    Flags: FI
```

My /etc/krb5.conf has

```
[libdefaults]
  renew_lifetime = 7d
  forwardable = true
  default_realm = EXAMPLE.COM
  ticket_lifetime = 24h
```

and my /var/kerberos/krb5kdc/kdc.conf

```
[realms]
 EXAMPLE.COM = {
  #master_key_type = aes256-cts
  max_renewable_life = 7d 0h 0m 0s
  acl_file = /var/kerberos/krb5kdc/kadm5.acl
  dict_file = /usr/share/dict/words
  admin_keytab = /var/kerberos/krb5kdc/kadm5.keytab
  supported_enctypes = aes256-cts:normal aes128-cts:normal des3-hmac-sha1:normal arcfour-hmac:normal camellia256-cts:normal camellia128-cts:normal des-hmac-sha1:normal des-cbc-md5:normal des-cbc-crc:normal
  default_principal_flags = +renewable
 }
```

**What am I missing to get a renewable ticket?**

---

Update:
I was able to make my tickets renewable by doing

```
kadmin
modprinc -maxrenewlife 7d krbtgt/EXAMPLE.COM@EXAMPLE.COM
modprinc -maxrenewlife 7d +allow_renewable newuser/mask1.myhost.com@EXAMPLE.COM
```

but this means I would need to do it for every principal. How do I make it so that all tickets are generated as renewable by default?

Comment: How come you don't tell us what the Kerberos back-end is?  Is it Active Directory?  Red Hat IdM? MIT Kerberos?

Comment: @T-Heron , it's MIT KDC

Answer (score 0):

You can set the default (as `renew_lifetime`) in [the [realms] section](https://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-latest/doc/admin/conf_files/krb5_conf.html#realms) of the `krb5.conf` file.